# How to redirect from a domain to another keeping the path component?

Tags: html, redirect, blogs, tumblr

I wish to redirect a page from a domain (properly a subdomain) to another maintaining the same path component.

I'm using a blogging service, not running a server; but I can edit the *global* head of my blog.

I've managed to redirect towards the main page of the other site using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://subdomain-2.domain.com">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://subdomain-2.domain.com"
</script>
```

But I'm not able to redirect *any* page of the first domain towards the *corresponding* one of the second — say, `http://subdomain-1.example.com/post/lorem-ipsum-123` to `http://subdomain-2.example.com/post/lorem-ipsum-123`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to grab the current URL and substitute the target domain to the original just by editing the head.

I suppose I can only use HTML, JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved using JavaScript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://" + "here-your-target-domain" + window.location.pathname
</script>
```

The key element was `window.location.pathname`. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/) I've found what I needed.

Comment: I use window.location.pathname alot, especially in tumblr, I find it very useful, so well done.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to redirect to a different domain is to directly set the hostname (not host) part of the URL like this:

```
<script>
     window.location.hostname = 'subdomain-2.example.com'
</script>
```

This will redirect you to the same URL (including protocol, port, query string, hash) but with the domain replaced.

Here is a nice visualization to understand all properties on the location object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#location_anatomy